# Uninstall or delete modules when upgrading 6 to 7?

Tags: 7, installation

Sorry to ask such a basic question, but I can't find an answer (and I'm an amateur).

I have a website that was written for me in Drupal 6. I want to upgrade it to Drupal 7.

There are quite a few contributed modules, and I realise I need to disable these before upgrading the core. Can I then simply delete the unused modules via FTP, or do I have to use uninstall within Drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated after re-reading your question. :)

The process for completely removing a module is generally:

1. [**Backup your site**](http://drupal.org/node/22281).  The [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module is great
   here too.
2. **Disable the module**. Admin -> Modules -> Uncheck module ->
   save.
3. **Uninstall the module** - Goto yoursite.tld/admin/modules/uninstall ->
   Check Modules to uninstall -> Click Uninstall
4. **Delete the module** - Delete module directory.

---

Additionally you can find details regarding [upgrading from previous versions](http://drupal.org/upgrade) of Drupal at drupal.org.

Another useful module is the [Upgrade Status](http://drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) module.  Listed only for reference.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not specific modules I'm concerned about.  I'm happy following the instructions for updating them.

Comment: I reworded my answer to address "can I then simply delete the unused modules via ftp, or do I have to use the Uninstall within Drupal?"  Sorry about that. :)

Comment: Crosed posts!!

Thanks, that answers my main question.

Cheers

Comment: If it did fully solve your issue, please consider accepting the answer with the check box to the left of the answer. :)

Comment: Damn! Wish I'd read your posts more carefully.  I missed the "unused" bit and uninstalled all non-core modules.
This caused me to lose Webform components!
Fortunately I am still playing with a test site, before the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to disable all contrib modules and themes:

```
echo 'UPDATE system SET status = 0 WHERE filename NOT LIKE "themes%" AND filename NOT LIKE "modules%";' | `drush sql-connect`
```

Also don't forget to clear the caches:

```
echo "DELETE FROM cache`drush sql-connect`
echo "DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap" | `drush sql-connect`
```

And make sure that you don't have any additional module inclusion in settings file (like memcached, cacherouter, etc).

To uninstall, you have to follow the standard process, or find/write some module which removes the orphaned tables.